# Does uwsgi server read the paths in the environment variable PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, uwsgi, pythonpath

Its weird because, when I run a normal python script on the server, it runs but when I run it via uWSGI, it cant import certain modules.

there is a bash script that starts uwsgi, and passes a path via --pythonpath option.
Is this an additional path or all the paths have to be given here ?

If yes, how do I separate multiple paths given by this option.

Comment: Path variables generally accept multiple paths separated by colons.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify multiple --pythonpath options, but PYTHONPATH should be honoured (just be sure it is correctly set by your init script, you can try setting it from the command line and running uwsgi in the same shell session)

Comment: Hey its an aws ubuntu 11.1 instance.
I have added the patsh to modules in both .profile and .bashrc in the home directory.
and when I echo $PYTHONPATH, I get them as well and I dont get any error on importing webob in python interpreter.
But when i run uwsgi and hit a python script with an HTTP request i get an import error.